# How to get rid of the glitch / delay in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using this code to show the splashscreen only when the user is visiting the app for the first time. This works, partially, but it's not working properly.

**When a user, who has already visited the app before, visits again, it first shows the splashscreen for just 1 second (so a delay), before it (eventually)  goes to the home screen... so it's like a glitch.**

Main controller:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");
```

In my *splashscreen controller*, I have this:

```
  if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
        localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
        $state.go('splash'); 
    }
    else {
        $state.go('home');
    }
```

My question is: how can I get rid of this delay / glitch? I find it highly unprofessional if a user can see something it does not need to see anymore.

Comment: This code snippet does not show splash screen if not the first time, so it must be somewhere else that shows splash unexpectedly. probably related to your route definitions

Comment: may be the state declaration default is set to home and your   condition checking may happening after that

Comment: I don't think it's because of my route definitions. I put this snippet in my splashscreen controller btw.

Comment: In ui-router use resolve option to wait for navigation

Comment: What do you mean @maurycy? Can you provide an example / snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two possibilities - 
1) Either you have mentioned splashscreen state as your default router and once execution comes under splash controller then only you are checking and make user land up accordingly.

2) Or if not splashscreen must be your parent state.

I suggest you move this logic to parent state and Make sure splashscreen is not your parent state.

Comment: I have this:  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");. You mean to change or remove this?

Comment: Yes, You need to redirect user to some other state by default. Inside which you are supposed to write this logic.

Comment: Alright, but what should I change it with, then? It's going to splash now. Should I remove it? Should I change it to home? I am clueless.

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

Add it Your home controller  - 

if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
        localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
        $state.go('splash'); 
    }

Comment: I did it your way... yet the glitch is still there. Right now, we just switched the glitch's place from home to splashscreen, that's all. Nothing changed in the way it works... because when you'd be a first time visitor, you see the homescreen for just 1 second first, before you are directed to the splashscreen.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a config.xml in the root folder of your ionic project. Inside you should be able to find these options

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2500" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="400" />
```

Adjust them for your needs.

Comment: And what should this do then? This wouldn't get rid of the glitch, probably... or would it?

Comment: you can set SplashScreenDelay to 0 for no delay or play around with the values a bit. At least angular 1 is pretty slow and sometimes the view needs some time to render.

Comment: I checked this and I saw that they are already on 0, so this is not a fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

With `ui-router` you can have few approaches

#### router config

```
$stateProvider.state("mainStateWhereUserArrives", {
  onEnter: function(title){
    if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
        localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
        $state.go('splash'); 
    }
  }
})
```

#### onStateChangeStart

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
    if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad'] != 'TRUE') {
        event.preventDefault()
        localStorage['firstTimeLoad'] = 'TRUE';
        $state.go('splash');
    }
})
```

You can put it in main controller on in `run` block

Comment: Where do I put the last snippet? The one beneath onStateChangeStart, I mean?

Comment: I've put a comment underneath, you can either put it in run block or the main controller if you have one

Comment: Okay, but what is rootscope? Can I just put that in the maincontroller and that would be sufficient?

Comment: I used `$rootScope` but you can use `$scope` as well, it's one of the angular services that you can inject

Comment: Nope, not working. Can't get onEnter working. Second snippet is failing as well. Probably because  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash"); , but can't get it to work.

Comment: Where do I put the second snippet? Because it gives me this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scope when I put in the maincontroller...

Comment: you put it in the first controller that is loaded and `$scope` has to be injected into controller, you probably work with `ctrl as` syntax so didn't had a need to inject it till now

Answer (score 0):

Use following piece of code for defining your home state in route.

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
    // dummy template and resolve things
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
    resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
    controller: function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = title;
},
onEnter: function($state){
   if (localStorage.firstTimeLoad != true){
     localStorage.firstTimeLoad= true;
     $state.go('splash'); 
   }
}
})
```

Its tested code and works perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm, what does the template thing to? And the resolve one? Can you explain the code first?

Comment: Its angular way to define a state where template is for ui, resolve is to pass data to your state.
Can you paste your code of state definition? I can explain better

Comment: It's like this: myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
 $stateProvider
    .state('splash', {
      url: '/splash',
      templateUrl: './templates/splash.html',
      controller: 'SplashController'
    })

Comment: This is what you need- 
//////////
            
         
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) { $stateProvider .state('splash', { url: '/splash', templateUrl: './templates/splash.html', controller: 'SplashController', onEnter: function($state){
   if (localStorage.firstTimeLoad != true){
     localStorage.firstTimeLoad= true;
     $state.go('splash'); 
   }
} });